# Git uncomitted file confirmation when switching branches

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, spring-tool-suite

I am using the git plugin for eclipse and I have noticed a problem with it and hoping this is a simple configuration change. Can anyone help?

When switching branches, the uncommitted changes are being merged across onto the newly checked out branch (only in certain circumstances). It seems as if this happens every time when it is "safe" to do so. The way to recreate is:

1. Create feature branch "branch1" from remote repository
2. Create feature branch "branch2" from same remote repository
3. Make changes on "branch2" and don't commit changes.
4. Switch to "branch1" 
   a. No confirmation message is shown.
   b. The uncommitted changes from "branch2" are merged onto "branch1"

I want to be able to force the commit message to appear (just like it does using git-bash). Is this possible?

Comment: @Gimby the referenced bug and proposed change is about submodules only. It won't affect the scenario described here.

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, this behavior is intended by EGit: a checkout is performed as long as the files to be checked out do not collide with the working directory. And uncommitted changes are left as they are.

If you think EGit should offer a different strategy of handling uncommitted changes I suggest to open an enhancement request: https://eclipse.org/egit/support/

In the meanwhile, you may want to (manually) stash uncommitted changes prior to switching branches. That's what I see most people do in this situation.